# Retrieve data from XML using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML:

**somefile.xml**:

```
<string
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SomeDataSet>
        <someData>
            <a>AAAA</a>
            <b>BBBB</b>
            <c>CCCC</c>
            <d>DDDD</d>
        </someData>
    </SomeDataSet>
</string>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of `c` (`CCCC`) using the following approach but nothing is returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("somefile.xml");

var_dump($xml);                           // returns the complete xml as a SimpleXMLElement Object
var_dump($xml->someData->SomeDataSet);     // returns nothing
var_dump($xml->SomeDataSet->someData->c);  // returns nothing
var_dump($xml->SomeDataSet->someData->c);  // returns nothing
var_dump($xml->someData->c);               // returns nothing
var_dump($xml->someData);                  // returns nothing
var_dump($xml->c);                         // returns nothing
```

Comment: What PHP version are you running? Tested it under whatever version I have active, no issues with `echo $xml->SomeDataSet->someData->c;`